# How to use bootstrap icons in blazor app ?(NET6)

Tags: blazor

I'm tryed but that doesn't work

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Much much simple to use WOFF and CSS:

1. Download bootstrap icons package
2. Copy `bootstrap-icons.css` and `fonts` folder under `wwwroot\css\bootstrap`
3. Add this to `index.html`
   `<link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

use the icons as :

`<i class="bi bi-chat"></i>`

WOFF fonts and CSS are cached by browser.
More quick to render than SVG.

Answer (score 1):

Download `bootstrap-icons.svg` from their website and place in a folder within `wwwroot`, for example : `wwwroot/images/bootstrap-icons/`

Example component using their chat Icon.

`ChatIcon.razor`

```cs
<svg class="bi" width=@Size height=@Size fill="currentColor" @attributes=@CapturedAttributes >
     <use href="images/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.svg#chat" ></use>
</svg>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Size { get; set; } = 24;

    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public Dictionary<string, object> CapturedAttributes { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

Usage:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" ><ChatIcon /></button>
```

This technique results in the large svg being cached by the browser. This can be observed in the network tab. After the initial load the icons load fast and are responsive.

I wrote this [utility](https://brianlparker.github.io/BlazorIconGenerator/) to further reduce the svg file size and create the razor for each icon I needed for my own projects.

Answer (score 1):

This took me forever to find this and I didn't see it mentioned anywhere.

Blazor needs the css file added to site.css in order to recognize the bootsrap-icons.

```
@import url('open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css'); 
@import url('bootstrap/bootstrap-icon[enter image description here][1]s.css');

html, body {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution from Elliott Harrison worked for me.
I added following line in site.css

```
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css");
```